# Android, turn on flashlight

Tags: java, android, camera

I've coded some things in order to turn on flashlight of camera. It works on most devices, but on some not, for example LG P970, it doesn't work.

In LogCat I see:

```
01-07 18:20:00.148    1272-2051/? E/CameraHal﹕ Prashanth initDefaultParameters 0
01-07 18:20:00.148    1272-2051/? E/CameraHal﹕ Invalid OLD Video Input  -1. Assume primary camera for capture (default)
01-07 18:20:00.156    1272-2051/? E/CameraHal﹕ setParameters: Invalid panorama mode -1
01-07 18:20:00.156   1272-21021/? E/Arc﹕ setParameters: Invalid panorama value: "-1"
01-07 18:20:00.179  18990-18990/? E/AF_SHR﹕ 18990:affw_eeprom_apply: AFFW : Error reading lens EEPROM
01-07 18:20:00.195    1272-2051/? E/ICapture﹕ 1272:haip_ipipe_find_id: Invalid file descriptor -1
01-07 18:20:00.210    1272-2051/? E/CrayonMediaType﹕ bChkMediaType Can't support [3] Media!!
01-07 18:20:00.210   1272-21031/? E/MPEG4Extractor﹕ both mdat,ftyp not found
01-07 18:20:00.218    1272-2051/? E/CrayonMediaType﹕ bChkMediaType Can't support [3] Media!!
01-07 18:20:00.218   1272-21032/? E/MPEG4Extractor﹕ both mdat,ftyp not found
01-07 18:20:00.250    1272-1340/? E/CameraHal﹕ setParameters: Invalid panorama mode -1
01-07 18:20:00.250   1272-21021/? E/Arc﹕ setParameters: Invalid panorama value: "-1"
01-07 18:20:00.250    1272-2050/? E/CameraHal﹕ Trying to set overlay, but overlay is null!, line:4858
```

What is **panorama mode** ? How can I set this value on **Camera.Parameters** ? These errors come while I'm calling **setParameters().**

main code of turn on:

```
    private void turnOnFlashLight() {
    Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<String> flashModes = p.getSupportedFlashModes();
    // Check if camera flash exists.
    if (flashModes == null) {
        /*
         * See TroubleShootingActivity, HardwareTestActivity that handle
         * this.
         */
        BusProvider.getBus().post(new HardwareSupportErrorEvent(TestItemType.Flashlight));
    } else {
        String flashMode = p.getFlashMode();
        if (!Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH.equals(flashMode)) {
            // Turn on the flashlight.
            if (flashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
                p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
            }
        }
        startPreview();
    }
}
```

**Thank you**

Comment: [Panorama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panorama) = wide angle view

Comment: @KEYSER why does it -1? And how can I set this value by myself?